# If x-axis is a tangent to a curve, show that it is also a tangent to another curve.

Tags: calculus

Question: If $x$-axis is tangential to the curve $y= a^2 x^2 + 6abx + ac + 8b^2$, where $a, b, c$ are constants, show that it is also tangential to the curve $y = ac(x+1)^2 - 4b^2 x$.

It's a problem from a past paper that I'm practicing for exam. I don't know from where to start solving this.

Comment: I think you may also need to show your work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{cases}
y=a^2x^2+6abx+ac+8b^2=0\\
y^{\prime}=2a^2x+6ab=0\\
\end{cases}\Rightarrow
ac=b^2
$$

$$
y=ac(x+1)^2-4b^2x=b^2(x+1)^2-4b^2x
$$

$$
y^{\prime}=2b^2(x+1)-4b^2=0 \Rightarrow x=1
$$

Substitute $x=1$ into $y=b^2(x+1)^2-4b^2x$, you will find $y=0$.
So it's tangential to $x$-axis.